# Get text position (coordinates) from .pptx slide

Tags: c#, coordinates, openxml

I want to get the position (the correct coordinates) of every word in a .pptx slide.
I tried doing that using OpenXml, but in the xml's there are only coordinates of the body rectangle and the title rectangle. However, it doesn't help me for getting the word's coordinates.